# S60 camera focusing

Tags: python, camera, s60

In my project I have to use mobile camera from my own program.
I use python with S60 platform under NOKIA 6220 Classic. It has 5mp-camera.

The problem is that photos quality are very-very low. Seems that auto-focusing doesn't work.
I'd like to know maybe anyone from you made something before. I can buy new telephone if I'll need this.
The main problem - quality of photo. I'm going to screen paper with text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a guess. Are you maybe getting low-res images that are suitable for sending via MMS? I would look at the API.